# Como carregar imagens web dentro de um ListView?

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Eu tenho um json mais ou menos assim (simplifiquei o original):

```
[{ image:"http://site.com/imagem.png", title:"Titulo", desc: "descrição" }]
```

Eu gostaria de carregar todo o conteúdo, inclusive a imagem dentro de uma `ListView` no app, eu tentei utilizar o `HttpURLConnection` dentro da mesma Thread, pra pegar o bitmap da imagem, só que isso faz com que demore muito pra carregar, e já vi em apps como o do youtube que carrega primeiro o conteúdo em texto(mais leve), e depois carrega o mais pesado que seria a imagem ou thumbnail, então a pergunta é: Como eu posso carregar as imagens de forma que não afete no carregamento do arquivo em texto, e em seguida, atualizar a imagem dentro do ListView?

Minha classe que herda de `AsyncTaskLoader<List<Dados>>`

```
@Override
public List<Dados> loadInBackground() {
    return QueryUtils.fetchMainData(url);
}
```

Método estático de `QueryUtils`:

```
public static List<Dados> fetchMainData(String stringUrl) {
    // TRANSFORMA STRING EM URL
    URL url = createUrl(stringUrl);
    List<Dados> list = null;
    try {
        // CONECTA NA INTERNET E RETORNA JSON CRÚ
        String json = makeHttpRequest(url);
        // PROCESSA O JSON E RETORNA A LISTA DE DADOS
        list = getImagemData(json);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Classe Dados:

```
class Dados{

    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    Imagem(Bitmap image, String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    boolean hasImage() {
        return image != null;
    }

}
```

Comment: recomendo que utilize a biblioteca Picasso. Lida com essa complexidade para vc como cache, etc... http://square.github.io/picasso/ . Tem um exemplinho que creio que resolverá.

Comment: Voce criou um listview customizado para todas essas suas necessidades já ?

Comment: Sim... so falta eu poder carregar a imagem independentemente do texto.